# PHP/Ajax Unserialize to JSON

Tags: php, ajax, unicode

I have an issue where I’m doing this with AJAX

```
$('form').serialize()
```

I than convert it or "Unserialize" it with PHP using:

```
$params = array();
parse_str($_POST['data'], $params);
echo $params['name'];
```

I then use `json_encode($params);` and save to a file.

My issue is, when I use a character like `’` or `-` for example, it serialises it to `\u2019` or `\u2010` which I don't want, I want it stored as `&rsquo;` or `&dash;` in JSON. I've tried absolutely everything to convert it.

I assume my point of conversion is on `$params['name']` before being saved to JSON, I tried flags like JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE but this isn't it either. I don't have `iconv` or `mb_` libraries to convert using those.

I believe the `\u2019` is Unicode? and I need it converted to an HTML entity and then saved to JSON as an HTML entity.

I know this is very bizarre, but it’s for a very specific reason, and I’ve spent about 5 hours now on Google and I’m depleted.

I’ve come to the conclusion there is no native PHP function that’ll do it, but is there a function someone has written available? or do I need to get `iconv` or `mb`?

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: It is a valid JSON, so if you use `json_decode`, it will turn into `’` and `-` again.